# How to open a link like www.gmail.com from code?

Tags: asp.net

I want to open an URL like [gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com) when a user clicks on a button.  How can I open this link in new tab from code (I want to read link from database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call JavaScript from Page Behind Code Like this.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
"onLoad", "openNewWindow()", true);


<script language="JavaScript">
 <!-- hide
 function openNewWindow() {
 popupWin = window.open('http://webdesign.about.com/',
 'open_window',
 'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0')
 }
 // done hiding -->
 </script>
```

**you can also do it using window.location("http://www.yourpath.com")**

Comment: I want to read link from database and open it in new tab. with this code How?

Comment: pass variable value like this function openNewWindow(dynamicPath)
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
"onLoad", "openNewWindow("+YourDynamicPathFromDB.Tostring()+")", true);

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onLoad", "openNewWindow('http://www.gmail.com')", true);

function openNewWindow(Path) {

}

Comment: Thank you,it works but open in popup window is it possible to open in new tab?

Comment: That's up to the setting of the user.

Comment: you can set window properties. There is code which override the nature of anchor tag target. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Response.Redirect
```

Method in ASP.NET to navigate to another web page.

Comment: Thank you,it works but if i want to open in new tab what should i do?

Comment: @iCoder remove your first comment then

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" onclick="openlink()"/>
<script>
    function openlink()
    {
       document.location.href = "http://www.gmail.com";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested before me use

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.gmail.com")
```

this should work as the method is designed also for absolute urls. Do not leave the http:// prefix.

Answer (score 0):

just execute the below line on button click

```
window.location="http://www.google.com";
```